# How to implement a powershell functions library?

Tags: powershell, code-organization

I recently worked on a project that we had to deployed using powershell scripts. We coded 2000 of lines, more or less, in different files. Some of them were dedicated to common methods but, after coding 500 lines for each one, it was hard to find what method to use or if it was necessary to implement a new one.

So, my question regards to what is the best way to implement a powershell functions library:

Is better having some files with lot of code than having a lot of files with  few lines of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where you can *store* all your script dedicated to common jobs.

Comment: I know the basis on Modules, but I keep on the same problem: one file with loads of script methods or loads of files with one method for each one?

Comment: @jaloplo IMO just one .psm1 file with all script, or more modules with scripts groupped based on your preferences use.

Comment: You are right, I didn't know the potential of modules till I read these articles http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/Converting-a-PowerShell-Script-into-a-Module.aspx

Comment: Looks like the Module link has moved, maybe to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-module?view=powershell-6) ?

Comment: @Elliveny and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/understanding-a-windows-powershell-module?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 5):

The answer from @MikeShepard is conceptually the way to go. Here are just a few implementation ideas to go along with it:

- I have open-source libraries in a number of languages. My [PowerShell API](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/api/powershell/) starts with the top-level being organized into different topics, as Mike Shepard suggested.
- For those topics (modules) with more than one function (e.g. *SvnSupport*), each public function is in a separate file with its private support functions and variables, thereby increasing cohesion and decreasing coupling.
- To wrap the collection of functions within a topic (module) together, you could enumerate them individually (either by dot-sourcing or including in the manifest, as @Thomas Lee suggested). But my preference is for a technique I picked up from Scott Muc. Use the following code as the *entire* contents of your .psm1 file and place each of your other functions in separate .ps1 files in the same directory.

---

```
Resolve-Path $PSScriptRoot\*.ps1 |
? { -not ($_.ProviderPath.Contains(".Tests.")) } |
% { . $_.ProviderPath }
```

---

There is actually quite a lot more to say about functions and modules; the interested reader might find my article [Further Down the Rabbit Hole: PowerShell Modules and Encapsulation](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/further-down-the-rabbit-hole-powershell-modules-and-encapsulation/) published on Simple-Talk.com a useful starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Christian's suggestion and use a module.

One tatic you might use is to break up the module into multiple scripts and include them all in the final module. You can either explicity dot-source them in a .PSM1 file, or specify the files in a manifest (.PSD1 file).

Answer (score 0):

I tend to have multiple modules based on subject matter (loosely, nouns).  For instance, if I had a bunch of functions dealing with MongoDB, I'd have a MongoDB module.  That makes it easy to pull them into a session if I need them, but doesn't clutter every session with a bunch of functions that I rarely use.  A consistent naming convention will make it easy to know what to import.  For example, modMongoDB.psm1 would be an easy name to remember.

As a side note, in 3.0 module loading can be configured to be automatic so there's no need to preload a bunch of modules in your profile.